# How to leave area for future dynamic activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I am trying to figure out how to make my layout have the following coded buttons stay in their place despite future dynamic activity, maybe through reserving a free space. In between the menu button and the other three buttons will be a grid of buttons with both random size and in random amounts based on preselections created dynamically. But no matter how many buttons or the sizes I want these four buttons designed in main.xml to remain in their proper positions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MENU" />
```

This is the area of concern. I want to make it where the menu button (above) is always attached to the top of the screen and the step, pause, and simulate buttons (below) are always at the very bottom of the screen.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/grid"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="STEP" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/grid"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/step"
        android:text="PAUSE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/grid"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/step"
        android:text="SIMULATE" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/speed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sim"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just figured out a solution my own question.
I had to use "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" after the menu button on the other three buttons, now any buttons added dynamically can be placed in between as needed.

The website wont let me answer my own question.

Comment: Whenever you use the words "dynamic layout in Android", you need to look into the Java code. XML, by contrast, is rather rigid and static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your RelativeLayout a LinearLayout. Give all Buttons "android:layout_weight="0"". Then at the desired empty space, add a View that has android:layout_height="0" and "android:layout_weight="1"". That should do it, provided I understand your question correctly.